# Unexpected behaviour of cut2 function: showing left end point value instead of range

Tags: r, binning, hmisc

I would like to bin my data and thought to use `cut2` from `Hmisc`package for that. However, if I enter exactly left end point value, I do not get the desired range, but only the end point:

```
> library(Hmisc)
> paste(cut2(seq(0,9,1),seq(0,10,1)))
 [1] " 0"      " 1"      " 2"      " 3"      " 4"      " 5"      " 6"      " 7"      " 8"      "[ 9,10]"
```

The expected result I get by setting the values a little bit off (`+1e-10`) from the exact values:

```
> paste(cut2(seq(0,9,1)+1e-10,seq(0,10,1)))
 [1] "[ 0, 1)" "[ 1, 2)" "[ 2, 3)" "[ 3, 4)" "[ 4, 5)" "[ 5, 6)" "[ 6, 7)" "[ 7, 8)" "[ 8, 9)" "[ 9,10]"
```

I am using relatively new version from `Hmisc` package:

```
> packageVersion("Hmisc")
[1] ‘4.1.1’
```

The reason why I would like to use `cut2` instead of `cut` is that the alphabetical order of the bins generated by `cut2` corresponds to the numerical order of the bins:

```
> sort(paste(cut2(seq(0,19,2)+1e-10,seq(0,20,2))))
 [1] "[ 0, 2)" "[ 2, 4)" "[ 4, 6)" "[ 6, 8)" "[ 8,10)" "[10,12)" "[12,14)" "[14,16)" "[16,18)" "[18,20]"
> sort(paste(cut(seq(0,19,2),seq(0,20,2),include.lowest = TRUE)))
 [1] "(10,12]" "(12,14]" "(14,16]" "(16,18]" "(2,4]"   "(4,6]"   "(6,8]"   "(8,10]"  "[0,2]"   "[0,2]"
```

Is this end-point behaviour of `cut2` function a bug or did I miss something?